# How to write a custom service host in WCF?

Tags: wcf

How to write a custom service host in WCF?
I want to have more control on service host.
Please guide me to write my custom service host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just need to derive from the base `ServiceHost` class. Anything else is totally up to you.

What do you want to improve upon? Where do you see things you need to do better or different than the standard ServiceHost class?

See these articles and blog post for samples and recipes on how to do it:

- [Of Hosts and Factories](http://hyperthink.net/blog/of-hosts-and-factories/)
- [Extending ServiceHost and the Service Model Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733086.aspx)
- [Custom ServiceHost Factory for WCF and IIS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120825221435/http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2008/02/21/custom-servicehostfactory-for-wcf-and-iis.aspx)

Marc

Comment: I know this is years later, but just in case... I would like to improve upon ServiceHost so I can add/remove multiple endpoints (especially MSMQ ones) programmatically without reinitializing the whole thing. Any ideas?